# How to rerender page I am at in React Router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do I get the component to re-render when I click navigation to the same page I am at? I have a item handle page that I would like to rerender without any location state on pressing navigation tab to it.

Comment: You should never need to do this in a properly designed react application. All data for the component should be in props or state that re-render only the parts needed when changed.

Comment: try location.key. Every time you click on navigation even if you are in same page a new loaction.key will generate.

Comment: If nothing (*i.e. state or props*) changed then why does anything need to be rerendered after a link is clicked? Is this an XY problem? You've *some other* issue that you think forcing a rerender will resolve, so you are asking how to force render? Can you edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are working with and trying to do? We can't help diagnose/debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best react-router features is that navigating does rerender the page unlike raw HTML style with `<a href="xxx" ></a>`.
In react, rerenders are done when you change your state or change prop. That is the proper way how to rerender. But you can force rerender with this line `this.forceUpdate()` but it is not recommended to do it this way. So choose whatever you like the most